# Convert JSON Array into Map using Jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson

In my application I am getting a JSON file containing a list of items, and I'm able to convert these items into an `ArrayList` using the `ObjectMapper` class:

```
ItemContainer container = mapper.readValue(json_input,ItemContainer.class);
ArrayList<MyItem> items_list = container.items;
```

I was wondering if it's possible to automatically generate a `Map` where one of the item fields is set as key. In the example below I'd like to generate a `Map` where the `"id"` field is used as key.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "ABC",
      "name": "Item1",
      "description": "First Item"
    },
    {
      "id": "DEF",
      "name": "Item2",
      "description": "Second Item"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: just create the map, then loop on your list. (java 8 would have stuff for doing that more functionaly, though)

Comment: @njkz2 wouldn't it be more convenient to create the `Map` directly from JSON parsing?